# Can I recover from a corrupted boot sector on a running system?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, windows-server

I accidentally ran a program the overwrites the protective mbr and all the gpt headers as admin, which means my system will die as soon as i restart it. I don't want to lose all my data, so is there a way to recover the disk headers from the filesystem data in memory on a running system?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please tell what program this was. Also add screenshot of DMDE partition TAB (see: https://youtu.be/XGDcQTPuubs).

Comment: oops - didn't read the tags, didn't realise you did this on a windows cistern

Comment: **Essential question** : When running Disk Management, do you see the EFI partition? Please post a screenshot of its entire screen and also the output of the `bcdedit` command.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can recover a deleted boot structure from a running system. This is a dicey proposition at best, and very most likely not possible while the system is running.

While the system is running, copy important documents and data to a USB Drive.  Do this right away.

Once you have your copy, you can rebuild your operating system.

Comment: ignore my previous comment now deleted if you did read it - did not realise this was a windows cistern

Comment: Yeah, even if there is a possible way to recover the system live, the first thing I'd want to do is make sure I've gotten a backup of the data while it's available in case the recovery fails.

Comment: Well, FWIW, it is possible if damage is limited to partition tables and boot records.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not fit the title of your posting. The protective MBR and the GPT contain partition table information whereas the boot sector is part of the one partition whose boot code is run.

As you were able to delete that information with admin rights in a running system you should be able to recover this information as well running `Testdisk`with admin rights. Testdisk specializes in certain disk repairs on a logical level and should restore both partition table and boot sector information.

Unfortunately you did not state what you did exactly so it remains unclear if the dammage you created is limited to partition table and boot sector information.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if we assume damage is limited to partition tables and/or 'boot-sectors' (OP is very vague about this) then it may be possible to repair this while the system is 'live'.

- Partition table: Either MBR 'classic' partition table + extended partition tables, or, GPT partition tables can be edited on a life system.
- Boot-sector: While these have a function on boot process, they also contain vital file system parameters. These too can be edited on a live system.

As @r2d3 suggested the Windows version of TestDisk can. I prefer DMDE, a more 'visual' tool. The *free version* can be used for this.

[image]

Re-writing the 'protective MBR' should be possible as well as adding 'lost' partitions to the GPT partition table.

Typically DMDE will designate lost and yet recoverable partitions etc. as 'found'. Such a partition can be easily undeleted by right clicking it > Edit > Insert the partition (Undelete). *It makes sense to check the partition contents prior to repair* using the 'Open Volume' option: There little use in 'undeleting' a partition that doesn't point to actual data (folder structure and files).

To actually write to disk, DMDE will make you jump hoops, start by selecting Disk menu > Device I/O Parameters, first TAB tick 'Allow Write'.

After jumping hoops, Select Disk menu > Apply Changes > jump more hoops and accept the option to save an undo file. Of course it makes no sense to save the undo file to the drive you're trying to repair, so instead select a USB pendrive for example so you can actually access it in case you mess up matters.

This all being said the wiser approach to all this is:

- Shut down the system
- Clone/image the drive
- Use a tool like TestDisk or DMDE to perform repairs off-line. Both TestDisk and DMDE can be used from a live Linux bootable USB drive.